# Cant return Derived class (Could not convert)

Tags: c++

I have the following derived class that is a subclass of `Eigen::Tensor`

```
template<int T>
class TensorD : public Eigen::Tensor<float, T>{
private:
    int tDim = -1;
public:
    typedef Eigen::Tensor<float, T> Base;

    TensorD(){
        tDim = T;
    }

    TensorD( const Base &d ) : Base(d)
    {
        tDim = T;
    }

    ~TensorD(){

    }

    TensorD<3> dot(const TensorD<2>& x){
        Eigen::Tensor<float, 3>& A = *this;
        const Eigen::Tensor<float, 2>& B = x;

        Eigen::array<Eigen::IndexPair<int>, 1> product_dims = { Eigen::IndexPair<int>(2, 0) };
        return A.contract(B, product_dims);

        //return AB;
    }

};
```

In the `dot()` method, if I try to `return` as shown above, I get an error:

```
error: could not convert ‘((Eigen::TensorBase<Eigen::Tensor<float, 3, 0, long int>, 0>*)(& A))->Eigen::TensorBase<Derived, 0>::contract<Eigen::Tensor<float, 2>, std::array<Eigen::IndexPair<int>, 1ul> >((* & B), product_dims)’ from ‘const Eigen::TensorContractionOp<const std::array<Eigen::IndexPair<int>, 1ul>, const Eigen::Tensor<float, 3, 0, long int>, const Eigen::Tensor<float, 2> >’ to ‘TensorD<3>’
         return A.contract(B, product_dims);
```

However, if I do this:

```
Eigen::Tensor<float, 3> AB = A.contract(B, product_dims);

return AB;
```

Then it compiles.

Why is this? How can I avoid the double copy?

Comment: It sounds like you are passing reference to 'const B' to a non-constant  parameter of 'contract'. Difficult to say without seeing declaration of the latter.

Comment: `TensorD<3> dot(const TensorD<2>& x)` looks like a specialization. Why is that included in the implementation of the class? If you create a specialization `template <> class TensorD<3>` and put that method in there, does it not work?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler does not allow an implicit conversion sequence that contains more than one user-defined conversion. I'm not familiar with `Eigen`; purely from your description, it appears to utilize expression templates. `A.contract(...)` doesn't return `Eigen::Tensor`, but instead an instance of some class named `Eigen::TensorContractionOp` which is presumably convertible to `Eigen::Tensor` - but not to your `TensorD`, as that would require two user-defined conversions.

Everything starts working once you split the chain by introducing an intermediary variable. With `AB` in place, you have an implicit conversion from `Eigen::TensorContractionOp` to `Eigen::Tensor`, and then a separate one from `Eigen::Tensor` to `TensorD`.

Comment: `TensorD<3>` does not have a converting constructor that accepts a `Eigen::TensorContractionOp` as input, that is why `return A.contract(...);` doesn't work. But a `Eigen::Tensor` can be constructed from a `Eigen::TensorContractionOp`, and `TensorD<3>` has a copy constructor that accepts a `Eigen::Tensor<float, 3>` as input, so that is why `Eigen::Tensor<float, 3> AB = A.contract(B, product_dims); return AB;` works.

Comment: Okay, is there a way to avoid doing a double copy then? Because I have to get AB, then after that do another copy constructor to convert it

Comment: It doesn't look like `Eigen::Tensor` was designed to be inherited from. By doing so anyway, you are going against the grain - you are going to have to fight it every step of the way. I'd consider dropping `TensorD` class entirely, and making `dot` a free-standing function.

Comment: Ah thats unfortuante. When I try to compile without my copy constructor, I do get alot of warnings. Surely there must be some smart way to avoid the copy? Can I just assign the pointer somehow, but I don't always want to do this

Comment: How do I return a reference to the object, so that at all times only 1 copy is ever made

Comment: Okay..i figured out a way, i can override the conversion for each and every operator function like this:

TensorD(const Eigen::TensorCwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<float,float>, const Base, const Base>& x)
    {
        this->base() = x;
    }.
But I would have to do it for every operator :(

Comment: However, this does not solve my problem of returning a reference.

Comment: I think you can write `using Eigen::Tensor<float, T>::Tensor;` within `TensorD`; this would [automatically inherit all the constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration#Inheriting_constructors) that `Eigen::Tensor` has. I'm not sure what you mean by "problem of returning a reference", and I still maintain that the whole idea of deriving a class from `Eigen::Tensor` is likely misguided.